# Differenza tra "lavorare in" e "lavorare su"?

Tags: meaning, verbs, difference, prepositions

Qual è la differenza nel significato di una frase tra il verbo lavorare più le preposizioni "su" ed "in"?

Comment: Non sono preposizioni articolate...

Comment: Nonostante siano già state date due risposte, penso potrebbe essere utile completare la domanda con degli esempi…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Lavorare in** 
è generalmente riferito alla sede o al luogo: 
"lavoro **in** banca", "lavoro **in** fabbrica".

**Lavorare su** 
implica una materia o un oggetto:
"lavoro **sulla** mia tesi", 
"io mi occupo del primo task, tu lavora **su** quest'altro".
Nel gergo comune viene usato anche per indicare il territorio di lavoro "lavoro su Milano" ma in quel caso  ***su*** è sostanzialmente una contrazione di "sul territorio/sulla zona di".

Per completezza c'è anche 
**lavoro a** 
per definire le modalità e i tempi contrattuali:
"lavoro **a** cottimo", "lavoro **a** tempo determinato", "lavoro **a** distanza".

Comment: Mi sembra che nell’esempio «Lavoro su Milano» (per dire «Lavoro a Milano / nella zona di Milano») l’uso della preposizione sia “regionale”: lo sento usare tanto a Milano, appunto. :-)

Comment: @Benedetta Non è regionale, ma è gergo professionale, tipico di lavoratori di settori specifici. Non ho riferimenti a portata di mano, ma "Lavoro su <nome di località>" potrebbe essere una contrazione di  "lavoro sulla piazza di <nome di località>", dove il sostantivo "piazza" è inteso in senso figurato come "zona geografica dove si svolge la propria attività professionale". L'ho sentito usare spesso da commessi viaggiatori, assicuratori e consulenti di impresa.

Comment: @Benedetta Ad esempio "Lavoro su Milano e provincia" -> "Lavoro sulla piazza di Milano e provincia".

Comment: @Lorenzo Donati, grazie! Se era questo il senso della domanda, allora forse la risposta dovrebbe essere ampliata.

Answer (score 4):

**In** indica il luogo: *lavoro in un'azienda tessile* o *lavoro in Germania*.

**Su** indica l'oggetto: *lavoro su un progetto meccanico*.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!